# Removing React project dependencies involving the es5-ext protestware?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've recently come to discover this ridiculous notion of **[protestware](https://www.wired.com/story/open-source-sabotage-protestware/)**.
In my particular case it is related to the lastest version of the es5-ext package.
The recommendation i've received is to downgrade to version 0.10.53.
Unfortunately, this is opening up a whole can of worms - compile errors that seem to be related to versioning/dependencies.

Is there any way to remove the es5-ext package from a React web application?

Comment: It's not harmful it doesn't influence in any way how the package works.

It just displays short text message on npm installation that's it. You can safely ignore it

Answer (score 1):

From this thread it looks like this issue, alerts a lot of antiverios and scanner and the post install file will be removed at the next major relese

https://github.com/medikoo/es5-ext/issues/186